# Which program allows remote management of Android devices?

Tags: multiple-devices, device-administrator

I have 50 Android tablets. I want to be able to control from a central place the following things on the devices:

- General settings like date-time, unlock method, display sleep time etc;
- Chrome specific things like clearing the history and cookies, saving bookmarks, setting the homepage etc;
- The ability to install or uninstall apps on particular device or all of them.

So I need a mini SCCM for Android. Is there such a thing?

Comment: I presume you're aware that the Device Management side of SCCM 2012 can do almost all of that out of the box (it uses the InTune service for the premises-cloud-device link)? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884158.aspx

Comment: No, I was not aware, but thanks. But I don't have SCCM, I just compared it to SCCM :)

Comment: Might [3CX](http://www.androidtapp.com/it-managers-easily-manage-android-and-iphones-3cx-mobile-device-manager/) offer a possible solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of [Mobile Device Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) services on the market, with varying focuses and feature sets.

Mainly mentioning this, as SCCM is mentioned in the question, but Microsoft's solution (that ironically is far better at managing iOS and Android devices than Windows Phone devices) is either [InTune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-intune/default.aspx#fbid=M-8ak-X7KWx) <sup>([1](http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2013/05/01/setting-up-windows-intune-to-manage-android/))</sup> (for a cloud-based subscription service) or [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/system-center-2012-r2/default.aspx#fbid=M-8ak-X7KWx) MDM <sup>([2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884158.aspx)) ([3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/gg675929.aspx))</sup> (if you're happy managing your own on-premises infrastructure servers).

A good round-up of current services can be found here: [10 BYOD mobile device management suites you need to know](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/consumerization/10-byod-mobile-device-management-suites-you-need-to-know/422). That round-up includes [AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/), [AmTel MDM](http://www.amtelnet.com/), [Dialogs Smartman Device Management](http://www.dialogs.de/en_US/produkte/smartman.html), [Exitor DME](http://www.excitor.com/), [FancyFon](http://www.fancyfon.com/), [Fiberlink MaaS360](http://www.maas360.com/), [IBM Endpoint Manager](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/ibmendpmanaformobidevi), [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/), [Symantec Mobile Management](http://www.symantec.com/mobile-device-security) & [Zenprise](http://www.zenprise.com/). I've trialled and had good experiences using three of those, and we're actively using one of them to manage BYOD devices at the moment, I think there are different winners depending on exactly what your needs are.

Comment: Superb answer, deserving lots of up-votes!!!