# Copy Android setup to many phones

Tags: multiple-devices

I've just taken delivery of a load of Galaxy S3 (mini) phones at my place of work.

Rather than configure them all individually, I'm looking for a way of setting one up (with our branding, security policies, required apps, etc), taking a copy, and then pushing that copy to all of the other phones.

Samsung Keis is OK for content only, but not really appropriate for this task it seems.

Can anyone recommend a way of achieving what I require? Thanks.

**Edit** - I should add that, as these are company phones, my employers are not to keen on the idea of rooting the phones.

Comment: Do you have root access to the devices, and a custom ROM installed (e.g. ClockworkMod or TWRP)?

Comment: I don't. With them being company phones they are not to keen on me doing this, so I'm ideally looking for a solution that does not requite me to root the phone. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pity. A Nandroid backup might have been the easiest way to achieve this. You might investigate into ADB backup, though. But I'm pretty sure there's a more decent way, probably some enterprise software.

Comment: Hint for a starter: our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)

Comment: Have you looked at [Mobile Device Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) solutions? Most of them can do security policies, required apps and some forms of branding without needing any complex changes to the phone (they normally install and run as [Device Administrators](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)), they can also run regular checks on the settings, instead of doing it as a one-off. See this question for some examples: [Which program allows remote management of Android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56857/)

Comment: Hmm, could be a possibility. We do use the Meraki MDM software, but that is not advanced enough to offer things like branding. It's good for pushing apps/credentials though.

Comment: Here's another one: [How to Remotely Mass Deploy Android Apps to Devices](http://www.androidtapp.com/how-to-remotely-mass-deploy-android-apps-to-devices/) (just found it in my bookmarks; I knew I had it somewhere ;)

Comment: Might want to take a look at [Android For Work](http://www.android.com/work/)