# centrally manage corporate android devices

Tags: remote-control

We may be about to start rolling out android phones/tablets in our company.
We currently use non-smart phones.

We would be looking for a way to centrally manage the devices - remotely administer/wipe, track location, remotely add/remove apps, lock down devices so users can't make changes etc etc.

If we could remote control them then that would be even better.

Any suggestions for tools that would allow us to do this? If they were free then even better.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at similar questions on our site, e.g.: [Which program allows remote management of Android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56857/16575)

Comment: yes i saw that, but as the thread was over a year old i thought things might have changed since.