# Centrally managing large number of android tablets

Tags: multiple-devices

I'm involved in a project that will deploy approximately 400 android tablets. All the devices are on the same network. Is there an easy way to centrally manage the following:

Creating and updating policies to restrict users from launching apps or updates
Update a custom written application 
Set device into kiosk mode and auto start an app

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've just put the correct tag on your question. You might wish to check [other questions using the same](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-devices). Probably relevant as well is the tag [remote-control](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control). Related question: [centrally manage corporate android devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/92036/16575) (and the ones linked to it).

Answer (score 0):

VNC server + shell script or try some thing like air_droid etc

Install in each tablet 
enjoy :)

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]! Could you expand this answer, like example of how to use shell script, and why and how Airdroid could help this problem? On Stack Exchange, answers are not only for the asker, but also for future readers. Not all people know how to use them (well, I don't). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resources to write the policy code yourself, to achieve this, Android has an API for affiliation to become [device administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

If you want an out of the box solution, there are a number of applications on the Play Store that does this. You should evaluate the balances between cost, ease of use, and required functionalities.